# Where can I find Metro theme control color definitions?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, microsoft-metro, baml

I'm trying to make my custom controls behave and look as others in the presentation framework.I tried looking through the GAC with ILSpy, and I can't seem to find a "Metro" definition.

Using colors defined under "SystemColors", don't come up with color matches to "native" controls.

Does anyone have any tips?

i.e.: The colors for hot tracking (within SystemColors), are not the same colors used by the WPF textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that "Metro" is really "Aero2". ILSpy is unable to peak at the baml for Aero2, but MSDN provides the source for Aero2.